# How to create discontinuous line chart with Google Chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I want to create a discontinuous line chart like this.

[image]

To draw the chart I wrote like this.

```
  function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Number');

      data.addRows([
        [new Date(2017, 1, 20),  460],
        [new Date(2017, 1, 27),  579],        
        [new Date(2017, 1, 27),  null],
        [new Date(2017, 2, 1),  679],
        [new Date(2017, 2, 6),  352]
      ]);

      var linearOptions = {
        title: 'Discontinuous Line Chart'
      };

      var linearChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linear_div'));
       linearChart.draw(data, linearOptions);
    }
```

I had to put a `null` value data to make it separate.

Is there a way to draw a chart like above from a data like these?

```
data.addRows([
        [new Date(2017, 1, 20),  460, true],
        [new Date(2017, 1, 27),  579, false],        
        [new Date(2017, 2, 1),  679, true],
        [new Date(2017, 2, 6),  352, true]
      ]);
```

This is a source code in jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/7jkmovqs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a `'style'` [column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available)...

use `stroke-opacity: 0.0;` to create a gap in the line

see following working snippet...

here, `null` results in the default style...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Number');
    data.addColumn({role: 'style', type: 'string'});

    data.addRows([
      [new Date(2017, 1, 20),  460, null],
      [new Date(2017, 1, 27),  579, null],
      [new Date(2017, 2, 1),  679, 'line {stroke-opacity: 0.0;}'],
      [new Date(2017, 2, 6),  352, null]
    ]);

    var linearOptions = {
      title: 'Discontinuous Line Chart'
    };

    var linearChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linear_div'));
    linearChart.draw(data, linearOptions);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="linear_div"></div>
```

---

note: there is a column role for `'certainty'` that takes a boolean value...

```
data.addRows([
  [new Date(2017, 1, 20),  460, true],
  [new Date(2017, 1, 27),  579, false],
  [new Date(2017, 2, 1),  679, true],
  [new Date(2017, 2, 6),  352, true]
]);
```

but this will make the line *dashed*...